# jQuery: Sliding Menu Elements Up / Down Depending on What Link is Hovered Over

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I want to use jQuery to animate a simple vertical menu that can be seen here:

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

When you hover over OUR SOLUTIONS, PRODUCT COVERAGE, OUT TEAM and CONTACT US categories, you will see subcategories open. Note that if one of the groups of subcategories is already open, it closes when you hover over another category link.

**I want to keep essentially the same functionality but have opening / closing of the subcategories animated.**

I would be grateful if someone could teach me how to do that!

Additional info:

The menu is located in the `<div id="access">`

Here's the CSS that makes it work:

```
#access {
position:absolute; 
left:50%;
top:140px;
margin-left:-600px;
    width: 280px;
z-index:99999;
}

#access ul {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
}

#access ul,
#access ul ul {
list-style-type:none;
width: 250px;
}

#access ul ul {
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display:none;
}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#access ul li:last-child {
height:77px;
background: url(images/aba/ABALink.jpg) no-repeat top left;
text-indent: -3000px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px #888;
}

#access ul li:last-child a {
background:transparent;
height:0px;
}

#access ul ul li:last-child {
background:transparent;
height:32px;
text-indent: 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

#access ul ul li:last-child a {
background:#fff;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
height:18px;
}


#access ul a,
#access ul ul a {
display:block;
padding: 7px 0 7px 10px;
background:#fff;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
text-decoration:none;
color:black;

} 

#access ul ul a {
margin-left: -18px;
padding-left:20px;
width:230px;
}

#access ul a:hover,
#access ul ul a:hover {
color: #CA0000;
}

#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
color: #CA0000;
}
```

Comment: Check out JQuery slideToggle function. Could be toggleSlide though... Whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this CSS:

```
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Add this JQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('#access ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').data('expanded',false); // set variable for all lists as closed
    });

    $('#access ul li').click(function(){
        if($(this).children('ul').data('expanded') === false)
        {
            $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown();
            $(this).children('ul').data('expanded',true); // set as open
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).children('ul').data('expanded',false); // set as closed
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. When I follow your instructions, nothing happens on mouseenter, but on mouseleave the actual link I hovered over disappears - until the entuire menu is gone. That's not quite the effect I had in mind. :-)

Comment: Sounds like some event propagation issue. Try replacing mouseenter with mouseover and replacing mouseleave with mouseout.

Comment: I think it's not that. The code is correct, but the selection is wrong. Your code tells the jQuery to select the same link. It needs to select the children - but I have no idea how to do that. Help please?

Comment: YES! This works! EXCEPT - now that I can see the animation, I realize that mouseenter and mouseleave are not the proper events for this. It has to be done on click. Could you please help me with the version of that code that does it on click, not on hover?

Comment: ALMOST - (thank you for being so patient!) - except this code opens new subcategories but doesn't close the one that were already open. So I end up with the entire list open.

Comment: By the way, that whole thing so far could be achieved with smaller code: $(function(){

    $('#access ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });

}); - but I do need to hide the ones that were previously open. Help please?